# How to register decorated objects in Dependency Injection frameworks (PicoContainer)?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, decorator, picocontainer

I want to wrap a number of classes implementing the Job interface with a JobEnabledDecorator object that determines whether or not it executes.

I am having trouble figuring out how to configure this in PicoContainer, so that it knows to create the Job implementation objects with a JobEnabledDecorator wrapping them.

Is this possible in Dependency Injection frameworks?

Is it possible in PicoContainer?

If so, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably want to add a "behavior."  The short story is, you need to register a behavior factory which creates behaviors that wrap your component adapters.  It's easier to describe when walking through an example.

First, you want to create a container, something like so.

```
final MutablePicoContainer container = new PicoBuilder()
    .withBehaviors(new JobEnabledDecorating())
    .build();
```

This means that, once the basic object is created - in your case the `Job` - you want to add something extra to it.  There are a number of built-in behaviors, but you want your own: `JobEnabledDecorating`.

```
public class JobEnabledDecorating extends AbstractBehaviorFactory {
    @Override
    public ComponentAdapter createComponentAdapter(
        final ComponentMonitor componentMonitor, final LifecycleStrategy lifecycleStrategy,
        final Properties componentProperties, final Object componentKey,
        final Class componentImplementation, final Parameter... parameters) throws PicoCompositionException 
    {
        return componentMonitor.newBehavior(
            new JobEnabledDecorated(
                super.createComponentAdapter(
                    componentMonitor, lifecycleStrategy, componentProperties, 
                    componentKey, componentImplementation, parameters
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The factory creates `JobEnabledDecorated` behaviors by wrapping the component adapter, which in turn provide your instances.  The real work is now done in this behavior.

```
public class JobEnabledDecorated extends AbstractBehavior<Job> {
    public JobEnabledDecorated(final ComponentAdapter<Job> delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Job getComponentInstance(final PicoContainer container, final Type into)
            throws PicoCompositionException {
        final Job instance = super.getComponentInstance(container, into);
        return new JobEnabledDecorator(instance);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescriptor() {
        return "JobEnabledDecorator-";
    }
}
```

`getComponentInstance` asks for the job, adds the decorator and returns this wrapped object as the new instance.  You'll have to add your own logic here.

```
public interface Job {
    void execute();
}

public class JobEnabledDecorator implements Job {
    private Job delegate;

    public JobEnabledDecorator(final Job delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("before");
        delegate.execute();
        System.out.println("after");
    }
}

public class MyJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("execute");
    }
}
```

Back to our container usage, consider this example.

```
    final MutablePicoContainer container = new PicoBuilder()
        .withBehaviors(new JobEnabledDecorating())
        .build();

    container.addComponent(Job.class, MyJob.class);

    final Job job = container.getComponent(Job.class);
    job.execute();
```

Running this will print:

```
before
execute
after
```

This is, of course, because the container handed you a `JobEnabledDecorator(MyJob)` object.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Unfortunately I can only give you one upvote!

Comment: It's helpful to you, that's what matters. :-)